# KDE Keeps freezing for some reason

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, freeze, plasma

First, to give a bit of details about my system:

- I use KDE plasma
- I use X11/Xorg as my protocol
- I use Arch Linux
- I have an NVIDIA gpu and an intel IGPU

Since I've installed Arch i have been experiencing issues with freezing. The most recent case of this was when I tried to change my window decorations. It is not limited to just system settings though, my system freezes when i open files, close applications, run terminal commands.. pretty much any action. This doesn't tend to happen early, for example for about 20 minutes I can pretty much spam closing apps, run commands and similar and nothing happens. Although the system settings freeze i can reproduce pretty consistently regardless of the online time.

I know some of you will ask about my journal logs for kde... but there aren't any, running `journalctl /usr/bin/plasmashell` will yield `--No Entries--`.

And for my OS journal, its a consistent repeat of these same errors:

```
pcieport 0: 000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Nov 25 11:14:16 archlinux systemd-journald[1212]: Missed 27 kernel messages
```

While frozen I have also checked my resource usage with htop, all i can say is that they are normal. Nothing being overworked and i always have free ram.

Comment: Have you tried switching to Wayland instead of X11? Also, you mention `htop`, does tht mean that the freeze is only graphical? htop continues updating while the UI is frozen?

Comment: I used wayland before and was told to switch to x11 to mitigate freezes. And to check with htop I open a tty (alt fn f3)